# Return Symfony Form submitted data as string, not array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I use Symfony 2.7.

Is it possible to get submitted data as string, not as array?

I have a custom form type for searching through records and I want it to have specific output. I want to use GET method on the form, so submitted data could be displayed and used in the querystring right away, without additional redirect:

Form is named *search* and has fields like
- firstName (text)
- lastName (text)
...

And if submit the form, I want the result NOT to be

```
search => array(
   firstName => 'John',
   lastName => 'Doe',
)
```

But I need it to look like

```
search => 'firstName:John lastName:Doe'
```

I tried to use data transformers for this, but no luck so far. Is it possible and how?

**form build** I am using right now:

```
    $builder
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ;

    $builder->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
        function($origData){
            return $origData; //no need to set form fields for me
        },
        function($submitData){
            $q = QueryResolver::buildQuery($submitData);
            return $q;
        }
    ));
```

The 'q' variable in second callback then really is

```
'firstname:john lastname:doe'
```

but the Request 'search' value is still an array:

```
  'search' => 
      'firstname' => 'john'
      'lastname' => 'doe'
       ...
      'submit' => ''
      '_token' => 'S9k9ZBPaUVz13nNGXn8UoRarxa37IHNWU_AJZGt00H8'
```

Comment: Data transformers are probably your best bet.  Maybe update your question with your attempted transformer code.

Comment: Updated question with data trasnformer code.

Comment: Ok.  Probably need to post your form type code as well.  The thing is, your input to the form needs to be a string as well.  The transform method needs to change ''firstname:john lastname:doe' into an array of firstname,lastname for the form to chew on.  I suspect you are trying to feed it two properties expecting to get a single property as a result.

Comment: And if you really are trying to combine two inputs into a single output then it's possible that the POST_SUBMIT event http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms might help.  I have not used this event myself so I can't really help on the details.

Comment: Ok, code is here, but its really nothing special here :).

Comment: Are you trying to pull data directly from the request object?  At a minimum you need to be using $form->getData() for anything form related to work.

Comment: Yes, I do. But it seems transformers work only for one single field. I Am familiar with form events, but all i could think of is adding another hidden field search, put the rebuilt query inside, then set the form name to empty string. But like this the query string will be mess with all the other filled-in fields' values submitted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89467/discussion-between-cerad-and-user2219435).